# Why put GO after SET?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I understand that GO is a batch separator -- variables, tables, etc are local to that batch. But I've commonly seem code like the following:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameSettings] DROP CONSTRAINT [GameSettings_EnablePremium_df]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameSettings] ADD  CONSTRAINT [GameSettings_EnablePremium_df]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [EnablePremium]
GO
```

I don't understand the significance of putting `GO` after a list of `SET` statements.

Wouldn't this imply that those `SET` rules are limited to what would be within that specific batch statement? In the case above, `XACT_ABORT` and `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` wouldn't be applied at all to the remaining code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any hidden 'significance' here, other than logically separating the batches. First set the session properties, then start doing work.
It would work just as well without it, but IMHO it kind of makes sense.

Remember that GO never reaches the server - it's a keyword used by the client application to separate batches, which means the server will see one batch with:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH;
```

These will affect the entire session going forward, not just the current batch.
Then another with

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameSettings] DROP CONSTRAINT [GameSettings_EnablePremium_df]
```

And so on.

For batch-scoped features such as local variables, this is more critical.

HTH

Comment: Clarification: it's even hard to call it a `keyword` - GO is not even part of T-SQL. SQLServer itself has no knowledge about [GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) - only client tools have knowledge about this instruction.